# uncaught reference error when i try to past the data

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

```js
// Function to transform the layout
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function transformLayout(productId) {
        // Get references to the original card and the detailed card
        const originalCard = document.querySelector('.original-card');
        const detailedCard = document.querySelector('.detailed-card');

        // Get the content from the original card
        const cardImage = originalCard.querySelector('.card-img-top_digitalcatalog');
        const cardTitle = originalCard.querySelector('.card-title');

        // Set the content in the detailed card
        const detailedCardImage = detailedCard.querySelector('.card-img-top_digitalcatalog');
        const detailedCardTitle = detailedCard.querySelector('.card-title');

        detailedCardImage.src = cardImage.src;
        detailedCardTitle.textContent = cardTitle.textContent;

        // Show the detailed card and hide the original card
        detailedCard.style.display = 'block';
        originalCard.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- New Product section -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container bg-light position-relative">
    <section class="pb-4 bg-light pt-5" id="new_product">
        <header class="py-5 text-center">
            <h3 class="display-1">New Products</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="container justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 text-start mb-2">
                    <button type="button" class=" btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle bi bi-menu-button-wide d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#new_product">New product</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#popular_product">Popular product</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#details">Details</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#similar_items">Similar items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2 text-end">
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search Original" id="searchInputOriginal">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-end mb-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary toggle-button">Toggle View</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex original-card">
                    <div class="card bg-white w-100 my-2 shadow-2-strong rounded animate-on-scroll">
                        <img src="digital_catalog_img/1.jpg" class="card-img-top_digitalcatalog" alt="Product Image 1">
                        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                            <h5 class="card-title m-4" id="product1">GoPro HERO6 4K</h5>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="transformLayout('product1')">Transform Layout</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card m-3 detailed-card d-none" style="max-width: fit-content;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img src="digital_catalog_img/5.jpg" class="card-img-top_digitalcatalog" alt="Detailed Product Image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

i want to pass the data in original card to the detailed card section. Imagine like you want to transform the layout of the original card to the detailed card but i got some error:

VM3241 digitalcatalog.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: transformLayout is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

help me to solve this or give me some code or idea that replicate my concept of transforming the layout of the card.

Comment: Why do you put the function definition inside the event listener?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
var transformLayout;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
transformLayout = function (productId){
//Code here
}
}
```